# object detection opencv blurriness

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, object-detection

I am new to object detection using USB webcam.

I have a USB webcam which is capable of recording at 30fps FHD. I've connected this camera to a linux machine to capture video. The USB camera is connected to USB 3.0 port.

ffmpeg command line is used to capture a minute long, 15fps, 640x720, bitrate 5M video.

A simple opencv based python program reads this video file, frame by frame using `cap.read()`. However, I've noticed that when there is an moving object (e.g. human) in the frame, it becomes very blurry. (Here is a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Pm4D.jpg) of an example) I am wondering if this is normal or some adjustments are missing.

I am asking this question because I would like to run an object detection algorithm (SSD + MobileNet v2) on this video that I am capturing. But for many of the frames, if the object is moving, object detection fails to spot the object. (Yes, of course there isn't a perfect detection algorithm for all video analytics and there are various reasons for it to fail object detection)

Could you give pointers to remove the blurriness of this video frames? 
1) Is it due to the video recording resolution is too low?
2) Is it because the python program is reading at different frame rate? (approximately 13~14 fps)

Comment: [_Many people tend to walk at about 1.4 m/s._](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferred_walking_speed) Recording with 15 fps then means, that walking people will have a displacement of about 10 cm per frame. So, most likely your blurriness will result from the low frame rate.

Comment: Or could it be the opposite? Recording it at higher FPS and analyzing it at a lower FPS could also result in blurriness?

Comment: Blurriness is due to "exposure time", which is how long the sensor is exposed to light to form an image. Generally, higher FPS means shorter exposure times per frame and therefore less blurriness. The exposure time - and thus the blurriness - was set when you recorded the video. It doesn't matter how slowly you read it back later during analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I'll take a look at it! Other than that, would there be any other modifications that could be made to have the moving object to be less blurrier?